# Replace values inside a for loop (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, compare

I'm working with a for loop that compares dataframes with different number of rows, and the comparison is working pretty good.
However, I'd like to replace specific values inside this for loop:

Data frame 1:

```
Product Color   Brand
0   A   Invalid Nike
1   B   Yellow  Invalid
2   C   Green   Puma
```

Data frame 2:

```
Product Color   Brand
0   A   Red     Nike
1   A   Red     Nike
2   A   Red     Nike
3   A   Purple  Nike
4   A   Red     Nike
5   B   Yellow  CK
6   B   Yellow  CK
7   B   Yellow  CK
8   B   Yellow  CK
9   B   Yellow  CK
10  C   Green   Puma
11  C   Green   Puma
12  C   Green   Puma
13  C   Green   Nike
14  C   Green   Puma
```

Code to compare data frames (suggested here btw):

```
def compareFrames(dx: pd.DataFrame, dref: pd.DataFrame) ->list:
    rslt = []
    print(dx.shape[0])
    for i in range(dx.shape[0]):

        dx_data = dx.iloc[i].values
        dref_data = dref[dref['Product'] == dx_data[0]].values[0]
        if dref_data[1] ==dx_data[1] and dref_data[2] == dx_data[2]:

            rslt.append('OK')
        else:
            rslt.append('Not OK')
    return rslt
```

However, I'd like to replace "Invalid" from Dataframe 1 with the correspondent value of Data frame  2, as follows:

```
def compareFrames(dx: pd.DataFrame, dref: pd.DataFrame) ->list:
    rslt = []
    print(dx.shape[0])
    for i in range(dx.shape[0]):
        dx_data = dx.iloc[i].values
        dref_data = dref[dref['Product'] == dx_data[0]].values[0]
        **if dref_data == 'Invalid':
           dref_data = dx_data**
              if dref_data[1] ==dx_data[1] and dref_data[2] == dx_data[2]:
                 rslt.append('OK')
              else:
                 rslt.append('Not OK')
    return rslt
```

However, it is not working!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question lacks specificity. For example, there are two possible fill values in df2 for products A and C. Which fill value is it you are looking for?

In this particular example, you might consider and alternative approach since all of your data is already in df2:

```
>>> df2[~df2.duplicated()]

Product Color   Brand
0   A   Red Nike
3   A   Purple  Nike
5   B   Yellow  CK
10  C   Green   Puma
13  C   Green   Nike
```

To get what I think you want, this is the simplest solution I could figure out:

```
# this solution will match the first possible result
def get_row(df1, df2, ix, search_value='Invalid'):
    s = df1.iloc[ix, :]
    if search_value in s.values:
        fill_idx = ((df1.iloc[ix, :] == df2).sum(axis=1) == 2).argmax()
        return df2.iloc[fill_idx]
    return s

pd.concat([get_row(df, df2, ix) for ix in df.index], axis=1)\
    .T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which returns:

```
Product Color   Brand
0   A   Red Nike
1   B   Yellow  CK
2   C   Green   Puma
```